# Error while using database in Java using SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite

Bank class calling the Atm class.The machine class contains the start machine method. Here onwards loop will run forever calling the required methods from another classes not relevant. The create table method should be called only once.Once the Pin is validated the program runs infinitely

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bank {

    final static int PIN =  5423;//pin to start the ATM operations
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the PIN to start the machine");
        for(int i = 3; i >= 1;--i) {
            int n = scanner.nextInt();
            if(n == PIN) {//if pin was correct , start the ATM
                Atm atm = new Atm();
                atm.startMachine();
                break;
            }
            else if(i > 1)
                System.out.println("Incorrect PIN. You have " + (i-1)  + " tries remaining");
            else {
                System.out.println("Tries exhausted. Contact the main office.");
                break;
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

Atm class which has start machine method

```
class Atm {//class for functioning of ATM

    Scanner scan;
    protected String load;//loading time 
    protected int cashAvailable = 2000000;//initial cash available
    static Database database;
    Atm(){//constructor to initialize fields
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        load = "00:00";//the loading time at midnight
        database = new Database();
        database.createTable();//call the database class
    }

    public void startMachine(){//start the machine
        Machine machine = new Machine();
        machine.start();//call the start method
    }
}
```

And the machine class

```
public void start() {//method to start the machine
        Withdraw withdraw = new Withdraw();//withdraw object
        Deposit deposit = new Deposit();//deposit object
        while(true) {//infinite loop for functioning of machine
            String currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());//get the current time
            boolean isLoadingTime = currentTime.equals(load);//if is loading time
            if(isLoadingTime) {//if yes, the call load method
                load();//method to load the cash
            }
            //show the welcome screen at every iteration
            System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Welcome to National Bank");
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");  
            Date date = new Date();
            System.out.print(formatter.format(date) + "  ");
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().getDayOfWeek());
            System.out.println("Press 1 to view your current balance");
            System.out.println("Press 2 to withdraw cash");
            System.out.println("Press 3 to deposit funds");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            while(true) {
                int enter_num = scan.nextInt();//get the preferred choice
                if(enter_num == 1) {
                    currentBalance();//method to show current balance
                    break;
                }
                else if(enter_num == 2) {
                    withdraw.debit();//method to withdraw cash
                    break;
                }
                else if(enter_num == 3) {
                    deposit.giveCash();//method to deposit cash
                    break;
                }
                else
                    break;//if not valid option
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the rest of the code that calls these methods.

Comment: I don't think that's needed and also that is huge.It might be a mess.Are you sure?I posted one method. Please check and help@forpas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious errors in your code in `update()` method are the comma after `SET Balance = ?` which you must remove and also change the indices of `stmt.setInt()` to `1` for `balance` and `2` for `accountNo` because you are passing 2 paremeters with that order in your `UPDATE` statement:

```
String change = "UPDATE accounts SET Balance = ? WHERE AccountNumber = ?";
try {
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(change);
    stmt.setInt(1,balance);
    stmt.setInt(2,accountNo);
.............................
```

Also, the error message:

> Abort due to constraint violation (UNIQUE constraint failed:
> accounts.AccountNumber)

means that you are trying to insert in the table an account number that already exists in the table and this is not allowed because the column `AccountNumber` is the primary key of the table so it is unique.

Also, inside `createTable()` what is `sc`? Is it a resultset?
If so, what are you trying to do? Are you trying to loop through the rows of the table?
The table is just created and it is empty.

From the code that you posted, I can't see why you get 4 times the message *"A new database has been created"*, because I don't know how you call the method `createTable()`.

Comment: Thanks.the unique constraint error is resolved.For remaining part, I will just edit the question.Also balance is actually the 3rd entry in the record and pin is the 2nd. so, i should be updating the 3rd entry only but after removing the comma, i get error: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2    @forpas

Comment: @nmnsharma_007 see my edited code for the UPDATE staetement. There is no 3rd entry in your UPDATE statement.

Comment: I don't understand. Look, in the table, entry 1 - account No(primary key),2-pin,3-balance,4-isSavings. After a transaction happens, I want to update the balance only which is the 3rd entry corresponding to the key(account number).  So how else to do that?@forpas

Comment: Passing parameters to an UPDATE statement has nothing to do with the columns and their order in the CREATE statement of the table. What is important is the UPDATE statement itself, so: `UPDATE accounts SET Balance = ? WHERE AccountNumber = ?` needs 2 parameters: 1) balance and 2) account number.

Comment: So what did I go wrong in my update statement? The key is account number so that should be after WHERE keyword. How do I update the entry corresponding to that key if my method is wrong?

Comment: @nmnsharma_007 I already edited my answer with the correct code.

Comment: Thanks a lot .Now I understand how the update works. I really appreciate your help. Just one more bug to go. The database is being created 4 times still. Why??I posted the method calling it.

Comment: The class you posted contains only the code that calls `createTable()` (only once). The problem is how do you use this class.

Comment: I added the main class of calling the constructor

Comment: The loop inside main executes `Atm atm = new Atm();` multiplie times, why?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the reason because the start machine method has infinite loop.I will just the post the relevant code now because the rest part is not needed anymore.

Comment: Add `break;` after `atm.startMachine();`

Comment: Yea, didn't work out. I added the relevant code now.

Comment: Then debug your code to find the point where it loops through createTable().

Comment: Yea. I was thinking you can't help me in this case because the code is just too big to debug for someone else like this. Nonetheless, thank you for your time and patience.